# How to make a curl command run asynchronously in CircleCI

Tags: python, asynchronous, curl, fastapi, circleci

I am making a call to an API which within one of the steps of a CircleCI job. However, this call takes a long time to complete and there are other steps/jobs within my workflow that does not rely on the output of this call.

As an example, this is what my `config.yml` for CircleCI looks like.

```yaml
job_one:
 steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
     name: Call API 
     command: | 
       curl -Lso /dev/null 'http://my_api.com/endpoint'
       echo "Doing other stuff here"

job_two:
 steps:
  - checkout 
  - do_more_stuff 

workflows:
 my_workflow:
  jobs:
   - job_one 
   - job_two
```

The API which I am calling is created with FastAPI. I know that you can define endpoints like so:

```py
@app.get("/endpoint")
async def endpoint():
 result = await some_library()
 # some other code 
 return results
```

But I think this only makes the code *within* the endpoint function run asynchronously. This means it can run `# some other code` while we await the return value of `some_library()`.

What I want to do is make the call to the API itself run asynchronously. My original solution was to do this (bringing back the above example):

```yaml
job_one:
 steps:
  - checkout
  - run:
     name: Call API 
     command: | 
       curl -Lso /dev/null 'http://my_api.com/endpoint' &
       echo "Doing other stuff here"
```

Notice the added `&` at the end of the curl command. However, when I brought this up, someone said that this would make it more of a **background process** rather than an **asynchronous call**.

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between these two things, and also how to properly make an asynchronous call in this case so that I can move on to other CircleCI processes while this call runs.